# Switchable dot access to Python dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, getattr, setattr

I haven't seen a toggleable version of dictionary dot-access yet.

My first-pass attempt here doesn't work:

```
class DottableDict (dict):

    def allowDotting (self, state=True):
        if state:
            self.__setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
            self.__getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
        else:
            del self.__setattr__
            del self.__getattr__

>>> import dot
>>> d = dot.DottableDict()
>>> d.allowDotting()
>>> d.foo = 'bar'
>>> d
{}
>>> d.foo
'bar'
>>> d.__dict__
{'__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setitem__' of 'dict' objects>, 'foo': 'bar',
'__getattr__': <method '__getitem__' of 'dict' objects>}
>>> d.allowDotting(False)
>>> d.__dict__
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

I think the signatures don't match up between setattr and setitem.

My second pass also seems like it should work, but fails in the same ways:

```
class DottableDict (dict):

    def dotGet (self, attr):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, attr)

    def dotSet (self, attr, value):
        return dict.__setitem__(self, attr, value)

    def allowDotting (self, state=True):
        if state:
            self.__getattr__ = self.dotGet
            self.__setattr__ = self.dotSet
        else:
            del self.__setattr__
            del self.__getattr__
```

Comment: What is the behavior you desire?

Comment: I sometimes like to use dictionary dot-access - accessing dict-derived instance values via instance.foo as an alternative to instance['foo'] - but I've wanted to be able to turn this feature on and off at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `self.__dict__ = self`, then the dict will automatically become "dottable". You can turn off the "dot-ability" by setting `self.__dict__ = {}`. The key-value pairs will still be accessible through indexing, however. This idea comes mainly from [katrielalex's bio page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398968/katrielalex):

```
class DottableDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
    def allowDotting(self, state=True):
        if state:
            self.__dict__ = self
        else:
            self.__dict__ = dict()

d = DottableDict()
d.allowDotting()
d.foo = 'bar'

print(d['foo'])
# bar
print(d.foo)
# bar

d.allowDotting(state=False)
print(d['foo'])
# bar
print(d.foo)
# AttributeError: 'DottableDict' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Remember the Zen of Python, however:

> There should be one-- **and preferably only one** --obvious way to do it.

By restricting yourself to the standard syntax for dict access, you improve readability/maintainability for yourself and others.

---

**How it works:**

When you type `d.foo`, Python looks for `'foo'` in a number of places, one of which is in `d.__dict__`. (It also looks in `d.__class__.__dict__`, and all the `__dict__`s of all the bases listed in `d.__class__.mro()`... For the full details of attribute lookup, see this [excellent article by Shalabh Chaturvedi](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html)).

Anyway, the important point for us is that all the key-value pairs  in `d.__dict__` can be accessed with dot notation.

That fact means we can get dot-access to the key-value pairs in `d` by setting `d.__dict__` to `d` itself! `d`, after all, is a dict, and `d.__dict__` expects a dict-like object. Notice this is also memory-efficient. We are not copying any key-value pairs, we're simplying directing `d.__dict__` to an already existent dict.

Furthermore, by assigning `d.__dict__` to `dict()`, we effectively turn off dot-access to the key-value pairs in `d`. (This does not completely disable dot-access -- key-value pairs in `d.__class_.__dict__` for instance, can still be accessed through dot notation. Thank goodness that's true or you wouldn't be able to call the `allowDotting` method again!)

Now you might be wondering if this deletes all the key-value pairs in `d` itself. The answer is no.

The key-value pairs are not stored in the `__dict__` attribute. In fact, a normal dict does not have a `__dict__` attribute. So setting `d.__dict__ = {}` simply resets the dict to a neutral condition. We could have used

```
del self.__dict__
```

insteaad of

```
self.__dict__ = dict()
```

too. However, since the `DottableDict` is given a `__dict__` attribute in `__init__`, it seems cleaner to me to allow instances of `DottableDict` to always have a `__dict__` attribute.

---

In the comments you note:

> Steps: turn off access, set d.foo to 'bar', turn on access, d.foo is
>   gone from everywhere.

To preserve attributes such as `d.foo` which were set while `allowDotting` has been turned off, you'll need to store the alternate dict to which `self.__dict__` has been set.

```
class DottableDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self['_attributes'] = dict()
        self.allowDotting()
    def allowDotting(self, state=True):
        if state:
            self.update(self['_attributes'])
            self.__dict__ = self
        else:
            self.__dict__ = self['_attributes']

d = DottableDict()
d.allowDotting(state=False)
d.foo = 'bar'
d.allowDotting(state=True)
print(d.foo)
# bar
d.allowDotting(state=False)
print(d.foo)
# bar
d.allowDotting(state=True)
print(d.foo)
# bar
```

By conventional, attributes that start with a single underscore are understood to be private, implementation details. I'm extending the convention here by introducing a private key, `'_attribute'` into the dict.

Comment: This looks much more like the amount of code I would expect something like this to take. I'm just figuring out where python puts things, though, and don't quite understand it. Why does setting `self.__dict__` to `{}` switch things back to attr lookups?

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation above.

Comment: I felt like I'd seen that `__dict__` was not searched by dot lookups, but I made a `class A(object):pass`, then `a = A()`, `setattr(a,'foo','bar')`, and `print a.foo`, and it spit out `'bar'`, so I guess I've been wrong. I have more questions, but I'm going to read the link you gave me first. Any remaining questions after that I'll ask as new questions on SO. I'm accepting this answer, as it does answer the question, is the smallest and most flexible, and removes all of the edge conditions I was fighting with. Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out how to not wipe out the properties when turning on dot access. Steps: turn off access, set d.foo to 'bar', turn on access, d.foo is gone from everywhere. If you can think of anything, please let me know. I'm trying dict backups and updates, but they're all failing in one way or another.